# Exclude some files during the minification process

Tags: webos, uglifyjs, enyo

WEBOS
ENYO : 2.4

Is there a way to exclude certain files when running the minification process using the ares command line in the webOS CLI

I have a JS file that seems to break everything during the minification process because of the the jquery identifier '$'

I get this error when I run the minified ipk on the simulator : **ReferenceError: Can't find variable**: $ .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems I forgot to include jQuery as dependency in my package.js file. Something so simple cause so much grief, arrrrrgghhhh!!!!

Comment: Well, that will do it!